# How does one know which creature was killed?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Following *Game of Thrones*' episode "Beyond the Wall" (season 7, episode 6), every article says that

> the Night King killed Viserion.

But how do they know its him, and not one of the others.

How do they know the difference between the three dragons?

Comment: Viserion is cream and gold in color.  Also, Drogon is being rode by Dany. So, not him obviously.

Comment: We know from the colour and subtitle

Comment: If you turn on subtitles it also explicitly says something like "[Viserion screams]" when the dragon is hit.

Comment: Duplicate of this question from the sci-fi/fantasy stack exchange site: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/167642/which-dragon-did-we-see-in-s07e06

Comment: @Aj: Mind letting me know why actually a dragon being killed isn't a spoiler? My edit was rejected by you and just after you rejected my edit you edited it in your self, with the only difference that you didn't kept my >!mark on the dragon part.

Comment: Since the answers are tending that way, the spoiler could be removed from the question altogether by asking it as "How do we tell which dragon is which?"

Comment: @Zaibis Because it doesn't make any sense to put `the three dragons` in the spoiler block. This thing is not spoilery and parts question between plain textbox and spoiler block which apparently harms readability. Plus we only encourage spoiler-free title.

Answer (score 23):

There are a couple ways to tell.

Size and temperament - One way we know is because Drogon has always been the favored one as far as which one Daenerys chooses to ride.  Part of it was his more aggressive, dominant personality.  He is also the one who seemed to sense when she was in danger when they re-opened the fighting games and came to her aid.  Her warg-ish bond seems to be the strongest with Drogon.  She always rides him, and not the others.

He was also the only one roaming free while the other two were chained underground in Meereen.  The history of dragons in this world has established, undisputed, that confined dragons do not grow and thrive as unfettered ones do.  When the fleet is burned in Slavers Bay, and Rhaegal and Viserion break out and join Drogon, you can see they are tiny, in comparision.  They obviously have grown, a lot, since being freed, but Drogon is still physically the largest.

Coloring - The coloring of the dragons, like the eggs they hatched from, are all different.

- Drogon - Black with red markings.
- Rhaegal - Green with bronze markings
- Viserion - Pale with gold markings

[Daenerys Dragons Differences Drogon, Rhaegal, Viserion - Refinery29](http://www.refinery29.com/2017/08/166962/game-of-thrones-dragons-names-differences)

Comment: You might also want to reference the screenshot in [Which dragon did we see in S07E06?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/167685) which shows that the closed-captioning explicitly states it's Viserion that is screaming when injured.

Comment: @Makyen - most US viewers did not have that captioning, and still were pretty definite that it was Viserion, so that didn't really play into my answer. Would make for a short, sweet and very definitive answer if you want to post one.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet all US viewers had the captioning. It's up to them to turn it on, no?

Comment: @sgroves - yes, but if it's in the original language and people understand it, they generally don't turn them on. So my comment, more accurately, s/b "almost no US viewers had captioning on."

Comment: In the show, are they ever explicitly named? With that I mean named such that it is clear which of the three is meant? Of course this is the case for Drogon, but I am not so certain that this is true for the other two.

Comment: @JarkoDubbeldam - To be honest, I don't recall it happening. We'd have to delve back into season 2, I'd guess.  When she first named them, while they were still purse-sized would be my guess if it happened.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet I searched the GoT scripts for "Viserion" and it was only mentioned once, in S05E01. Imma watch it real quick to see if anything can be made of that.

Comment: Hmm, no. That is a moment where she calls out at both of the two dragons in the dungeon in mereen. There are no dragons visible at the time, so it is unclear which is meant.

Answer (score 7):

Description of Viserion is as follows:

> He can be distinguished by his cream and gold colored scales, and
>   red-orange wings

This is clearly distinguishable from Rhaegal, whose description is as follows:

> He can be distinguished by his green and bronze colored scales, and
>   his yellow-orange colored wings.

It was clearly not Drogon, as Dany was on him. She is known to use only Drogon as her chariot throughout the show.

[Personal Opinion] Danaerys is their mother. So, she must obviously know which one was fell, from the look of it.

The cream-colored wings can easily identified in the killing clip too:

Comment: While I'm sure she knows, I don't think she ever explicitly points out (in that episode, anyway) which one it was. The question is more about how the Internet community was able to jump all over that ID right away, I think.

Comment: I'd found in season 7, they've been much harder to tell apart than when they were in Slaver's Bay. For me, it had become Drogon... and the other two.

Comment: I mentioned this on the other answer as well. Are Viserion and Rhaegal actually named in the show? The only moment I could find where Viserion's name was mentioned, was in S05E01. I can't watch it right now to check if from there it is clear which is which, but otherwise we only really have the books to go off to visually tell them apart.

Answer (score 7):

The close captioning makes it pretty clear which of the dragons is hit:

[image]

Picture taken from [this post on Scifi.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/167642/which-dragon-did-we-see-in-s07e06/167685#167685)

While the other answers give descriptions of the dragons, I am not sure if they were explicitly named and/or described in the show itself.